# Junit 5 and Mockito 3: UnnecessaryStubbingException not thrown when injecting @Mock's through constructor

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

Looking at the two test classes below I assume the same behavior from them: to have an `UnnecessaryStubbingException` thrown. However `MyTest2` does not. The `MockitoExtension` class should have strictness set to strict stubs by default. I can't seem to find any documented information about this behavior and I really want to understand it.

I prefer to write my tests as `MyTest2` because I like to have final fields wherever possible, though I also really enjoy the strict stubs check done by Mockito.. Please help my understand the difference between the two tests.

```
package example;

import java.util.List;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyTest {

  @Mock
  List<Integer> integerList;

  @Test
  void test() {
    Mockito.when(integerList.size()).thenReturn(10);

    System.out.println("Do something not involving list");

    Assertions.assertTrue(true);
  }
}

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyTest2 {

  final List<Integer> integerList;

  MyTest2(@Mock List<Integer> integerList) {
    this.integerList = integerList;
  }


  @Test
  void test() {
    Mockito.when(integerList.size()).thenReturn(10);

    System.out.println("Do something not involving list");

    Assertions.assertTrue(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: At the point at which the unit ParameterResolver creates the mock, the UniversalTestListener hasn't yet been created (that happens in DefaultMockitoSession()), and so mockito doesn't know about that mock. Seems like a bug.

Comment: Hmm, that's good info. Maybe I should try and contact the developers for Mockito then.

Answer (score 3):

I found the reason in the [mockito documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/exceptions/misusing/UnnecessaryStubbingException.html):

> Mockito JUnit Runner triggers UnnecessaryStubbingException only when none of the test methods use the stubbings. This means that it is ok to put default stubbing in a 'setup' method or in test class constructor. That default stubbing needs to be used at least once by one of the test methods.

If you do not want the exception to be thrown for the `MyTest` class, you can use [Mockito.lenient](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.5.13/org/mockito/Mockito.html#lenient--) or [MockitoSettings](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter/3.5.13/org/mockito/junit/jupiter/MockitoSettings.html). But I guess it is not possible to activate the exception for the `MyTest2` class.

Comment: I don't setup any stubbing in the outside of the test though. So I don't really agree this being the reason for the exception not being thrown. :(